Some objects don't appear in Geometry Nodes
(Following the Blender Guru Donut Tutorial)
So, I have a layout with some donuts (which have icings on top) on a plate, as shown below:

In order to add those sprinkles on top of the icing, we went to the "Geometry Nodes" tab, and created some flow.
Now I'm trying to reuse the same geometry nodes flow to add sprinkles to the plate.
But to my surprise, when I enter the "Geometry Nodes" tab, everything disappears and only the icings remain (picture below).

Question
Why are the donuts and plate not appearing in Geometry Nodes? (It's not about having a bad node tree! It's simply about "entering the tab" Geometry nodes)
How can I make them appear? (It's like they're simply "not available")


I do not see any Geometry Nodes nodetree in your screenshot to examine what could be wrong there or why your objects disappear.

The point is: there is no problem in the node tree! It's not about the node tree. At this moment, the plate and the donuts DON'T have a node tree

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

@DanielMöller You wrote "why are the donuts and plates not appearing in Geometry Nodes", so I assume there has to be a nodetree where you want them to appear...? Show us where they are "not available" or probably even better upload the file as StefLAncien suggests.

They simply don't appear, it's literally in the picture. I can't see them there. They appear fine everywhere else, but the moment I click the tab "Geometry Nodes", they disappear (that is totally independent on the tree, they may have a tree or not, they don't appear in the tab "Geometry Nodes") -- There is literally "no change" I made to the objects in the two pictures above. One picture is in the "layout" tab, the other picture is in the "geometry nodes" tab. Simply alternating tabs change their visibility.

Alright... that may sound incredibly silly, but you can press "/" (forward slash) to isolate/unisolate objects in view.
For some reason, the "Geometry Nodes" tab retained some weird isolation (of multiple objects) independently from the "Layout" tab.
